# Using overflow without a specific height property value

Tags: css, vuetify.js

Is it possible not to specify a specific height value? Only need block 2/2 scrolling

That's what I did
https://codepen.io/pysdbi/pen/YzxREKV

```
<v-row class="d-flex align-stretch info">
  <v-col class="overflow-auto" style="height: 100%">
    2/2
    <v-sheet>
      <v-btn v-for="n in 42" :key="n" class="my-2" block>
        {{ n }}
      </v-btn>
    </v-sheet>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

Overflow needs a specific height in order for it to work. That being said, we can work around it by using a calculated height, and so the height will be specified but will not be necessarily "fixed".

You can use 100vh to set the height to 100% viewport height. Thus, we only need to subtract the top row. This way, that table is set to 100% minus the height of the first row.

Your style binding will look something like this: style="height: calc(100vh - 180px)". You may need to play around with the 180px to make it fit.